# HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 how to choose correct heatsink?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, central-processing-unit, hardware

We purchased a new HP Proliant DL360 gen8 server (670640-425) (HP DL360p Gen8 E5-2620 Base EU)

at the same time we purchased the cpu/heat-sink package for a 2nd CPU (654782-B21) (HP DL360p Gen8 E5-2620 Kit).

The problem is that the motherboard had the "screw ON Heat-sink" (735506-001) while the part we ordered had the "latch on heat-sink" (667888-001).

I have asked HP support for help on this, but have not received an answer yet (been a day or so).

The question is.. when I order servers, how do I know what type heat-sink I should buy? (without having to open it and look inside the server).

Comment: Work with your sales rep.  They have their uses, and this is one of them.

Comment: yeah, the sales rep said.. I do not know... so I guess I will not use this company any more.

Comment: I just got a reply from HP support, and I think others will face this problem, and could save a lot of time, if the question was opened again, and I was allowed to answer my own question. (it took HP Support several days to get back to me),

Comment: All the Gen8 servers that were shipped before November, 2013 will have Latch type heat sink. The server that were shipped after November, 2013 will go with Screw Down heat sink. So, the other way to make sure is to check server shipped date. If you are planning to purchase any server in future, all of them will have screw down heat sink as it has been stopped since November 2013. So, the best way to make sure is to confirm if the servers you are planning to processor upgrade are servers shipped before November 2013 or after that. This way you could be sure what kind of heat sink we have.

Answer (score 3):

HP CPUs are sold as kits, which include the CPU, heatsink and thermal paste. You should never need to buy something like a heatsink separately during a normal purchasing process. If you do, you should reference the spare-part number listed on the component and order that... You can also look at the spare-part or option part number on your existing CPU kit.

More importantly, you and your vendor have [access to the parts lists and Quickspecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14211_na/14211_na.pdf) and should use them to guide configuration changes. In this situation, two processor SKUs were available, and you basically ordered the wrong one.

The DL3x0p Gen8 product line has been revised slightly, so there are two types of system boards available in the field. HP details this in *[**this support bulletin**](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/mostViewedDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c03928282-2%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.tpst=efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01&sp4ts.oid=5177953&ac.admitted=1396615871634.876444892.492883150)*. In the future, look at the server to determine the motherboard revision.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I ordered the two together, so I had not got the chance to look at the motherboard yet... I wish to know how I can know what type of motherboard, from the model number or such. and my vendor sucks.. I guess

Comment: You can determine this with the serial number.

Comment: I do not think they usually give out the serial of a server before it is purchased...